# Calculating Percentage Efficiency

Tags: percentages

I am processing payments each payment consists of 2 parts, A takes 1 minute and part B takes 5 minutes, to process a batch of 5 payments takes 1+1+1+1+1+5+5+5+5+5=30 minutes, but I have a way that would reduce the number of B parts to 5 minutes no matter how many payments are in each batch. So for 5 payments this becomes 1+1+1+1+1+5=10 minutes. How do I calculate how much more efficient the newer process is over the old as a percentage e.g. New is 75% more efficient than Old, given that the time taken for part A may change part but B won't.

Comment: How do you define efficiency?

Comment: @LucioTanzini As a reduction in the overall time taken to complete a batch.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the time neede as a frame of reference, see, efficiency works well for example with energy, because there is a maximum efficiency you cannot even theoretically surpass

Comment: @LucioTanzini How would I calculate time needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency depends on the number of payments $n $.
So the formula is easy to find: $6n-n-5$ is the differnce in time, $(5n-5)/(6n) $ is the ratio of the saved time over the initial time required.
  You could also state the formula like this: $\frac {5}{6}-\frac{5}{6n} $

Indeed, the time required from the second system is $n+5$, as each payment takes 1 minute and tnere are 5 minutes you always have to add.

Not that the second system woukdn't be more efficient only in the absurd case of no payment at all, but with different systems you may want to predict how many payments you'll receive in order to employ the best "strategy".